# Get name of T in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need help with typeScript.

How to get the T interface name from this code:

```
interface User 
  {
      id    : number,
      name  : string
  }

  interface UserData 
  {
      id    : number,
      user_id    : number,
      key  : string,
      value  : string
  }



  function get<T>(){
    const type = typeof(T);
}

get<User>();
get<UserData>();
```

the first line in get() method return an error:

```
const type = typeof(T);
```

How to get the type of T?

thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with that information? Types don't necessarily exist at runtime.

Comment: The short answer to this is "you can't".  Both `get<User>()` and `get<UserData>()` in TypeScript compile to the JavaScript `get()`.  Seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); what is the underlying use case?

Comment: Also worth noting `interface` are abstract, IOW: you can't create instances of them, so if your after a function called `get` that returns some object that's User or UserData, it's classes your probably looking for not, interfaces.  IOW: are you after a factory pattern?..

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you would need to have a parameter of type T as input. Else you don't have anything to check the type on.
As far as I know there is no typeof() function. The syntax is "typeof 'What you want to check'" -> (this would return in string).
You could use the below code. But this will not satisfy you, because it will always be object because of typescript compiling to javascript.

```
 function get<T>(arg: T){
console.log(typeof arg);
} // will return object
```

Comment: in c# there is a method name :             Type type = arg.GetType();